# In Node.js, what is the equivalent of Python's pip freeze

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm

What is the equivalent of Python's `pip freeze` to create a snapshot list of all the npm modules being used and their current versions? And Python's `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt` so the environment can be reproduced.

On a side note, Meteor.js automatically tracks all packages in `.meteor/packages.json` and ensures those dependencies whenever a change is made to that file, so I believe it can be done on Node.js.

Comment: Questions asking for a third party library solution are considered off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm shrinkwrap` should do it. [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap)

Comment: Do we do `npm init` first followed by `npm shrinkwrap`?